# Linq to SQL Unable to cast object

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I am binding my Product table to Grid like this

Action Controller

```
ViewData["Products"] = _repository.GetProducts(true);
```

View

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid((IEnumerable<Product>)ViewData["Products"])
```

And everything works fine. But I need to select two fields only from Table and I tried to use code below

```
ViewData["Products"] = _repository.GetProducts(true).Select(p => new
{
Id = p.Id,
Name = p.Name
});
```

and now I get error below. Maybe someone could explain hot to solve this problem?

```
Unable to cast object of type System.Data.Linq.DataQuery to type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this:

```
ViewData["Products"] = _repository.GetProducts(true).Select(p =>  new 
KeyValuePair<int,string>
(
   p.Id,
   p.Name
)).ToList();
```

And then change this:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid((List<KeyValuePair<int,string>>)ViewData["Products"])
```